# MVC Get user password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, password-protection

I'm well aware that passwords should be hashed and then saved to the database. But in my situation, I need to get the User's Username and Password in order to activate their accounts on my Linux VPS.

Depending on which server they subscribe on, they'll be reactivated on a monthly basis, so I'll need access to user passwords at all times (not just when they register).

Is there a way to store the passwords in the database unhashed or would that be too risky?

Comment: Sure you can store in unhashed, but it's literally a huge security problem.  The real question is, why do you need the password on the website?  Why can't you have a secure backend (API) that can do the impersonation without having to expose passwords at the website?

Comment: Ask yourself this, "Would I trust anyone to store my password unencrypted?"

Comment: All the more reason. I don't think you'd actually deserve "honors" for storing unsecured plain-text passwords.